# How do i turn on Reset lock on my phone?

Tags: settings, windows-10-mobile, nokia-lumia-730

I own a Nokia Lumia 730.. Recently updated it to windows 10.
I am not able to find the reset lock on my phone. Since the settings menu has changed and there is no option that i can see to turn that on.
Can somebody help me with this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This has changed with Windows 10 Mobile. From Microsoft's documentation:

> When you set up your phone, sign in with your Microsoft account and
>   accept the recommended settings. That's all you need to do to turn on
>   Reset Protection. If you don't turn it on during setup, you can always
>   go to Settings > Updates & security > Find my phone
>   later and do it there.
>
> After you turn on Reset Protection, you'll get a "Welcome to Reset
>   Protection" confirmation sent to the email address
>   associated with your Microsoft account.

[Source](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/protect-my-phone)

So it would appear that it should automatically be turned on if you've turned on Find My Phone.

Comment: It doesn't show there for me, with a Lumia 950 (And the [checker](http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/p/?LinkId=615903) reports reset protection as off)

Comment: @RowlandShaw Hmm, that's interesting. Perhaps there's differences if you, say, restore from a backup or upgrade vs a clean reset?